# How can I get device Locale or Language with PhoneGap Build?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, globalization

I'm using Phonegap Build to develop an application for iOS and Android.

I'd like to determine the locale (e.g. 'en-US') for the device, though I'd settle for the current language setting, or even the app store my app was installed from (it's been a long day).

Following the instructions [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html) for the Globalization plugin I think I have everything right, but nothing seems to work on either the iPhone 6 or Samsung Galaxy Nexus I'm using for testing.

The relevant part of my config.xml looks like this:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
```

My function for getting locale from the plugin looks like this:

```
var getPhoneGapLocaleName = function() {
    var loc = 'unknown';

    if (navigator.globalization !== undefined) {
        navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
            function (locale) {
                if (locale !== undefined) {
                        loc = locale.value;
                }
            },
            function () {
                // nothing
            }
        );
    }

    return loc;
};
```

Note: on both devices navigator.globalization.getLocaleName is present and appears correct, evaluating to a function resembling what I'd expect based on the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here was that the variable 'loc' was declared outside the scope of the success or failure callbacks, which of course happen after a few brief moments.

I fixed this by changing the function thus:

```
var refreshPhoneGapLocaleName = function() {
    if (navigator.globalization !== undefined) {
        navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
            function (locale) {
                if (locale !== undefined) {
                    localStorage['pg.locale'] = locale.value;
                }
            },
            function () {
                // nothing
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Now calling it in onDeviceReady in order to refresh the values when the app starts.

A few moments later (not immediately) the following function can be used to retrieve the locale value:

```
var getLocale = function() {
    return localStorage['pg.locale']();
};
```

The greatest thing about StackOverflow is how often it helps one to resolve one's own silly mistakes. :)

Answer (score 2):

*Although previous answers are returning the desired result, and giving an option to retrieve the current phonegap locale name, they did not explain the topic starter why his function did not work, and how to adjust his function to work in the way he intended (i.e. not using localStorage and not showing the locale in the console but giving the answer in real-time as a result)*

I am posting this answer since I was looking for a quick function to get the device locale, and this post was my first result. While the opening post gave me everything I needed, I would like to answer this question for future visitors with the same purpose I had. Sorry for posting to a topic this old, but I hope I can help others with my answer.

The reason the function of topic starter does not work is the following: the plugin returns the locale in an asynchronous way. Therefore, the **loc =locale.value** line is only executed after the function's return statement. To fix this, we can write a wrapper function to simplify the plugins output as follows. Keep in mind that we need to use this function asynchronously, since the  plugin result is also asynchronous.

The function:

```
var getPhoneGapLocaleName = function ( callback ) {
    var unknownLocation = 'unknown'; //Default value
    if ( navigator.globalization !== undefined ) {
        navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
            function ( locale ) {
                if ( locale !== undefined ) {
                    callback( locale.value );
                } else {
                    callback( unknownLocation );
                }
            },
            function () {
                callback( unknownLocation );
            }
        );
    } else {
        callback( unknownLocation );
    }
};
```

Use the function like this:

```
getPhoneGapLocaleName( function( loc ){ console.log( 'The locale was set as follows: ' + loc ); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

When the browser is set to the en_US locale, this should display a popup dialog with the text language: English:

navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(

```
function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
```

);

Full Example

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>getPreferredLanguage Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function checkLanguage() {
      navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
        function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
        function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
      );
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="checkLanguage()">Click for language</button>
  </body>
</html>
```